# validate value while typing in the texbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying a task in which there is a input field for loan amount which should range between 5k to 10k.
its should while typing in the textbox itself.
(i.e) if i enter starting 2 or 3 or 4 as number it should show the alert box.
i have coded to display the alterbox but its show after moving to another textbox.
could anyone find what wrong i have done.?

```
<input type="text"  id="loan_amt" name="loanamt"  onkeyup="calemi();" onblur="rangeforloanamt(this);"/>

function rangeforloanamt(givenval) //Customer loan form : loan amount minimum and maximum value validation
    {
        if(!(givenval.value >= 50000 && givenval.value <= 100000))
            {
                alert("enter loan amount between 50000 and 100000");  
                return false;
            }
    }
```

here is my code.. and thanks in advance

Comment: What is `calemi` function?

Comment: actually that is for another function.. calculating emi.. once u start putting value in the texbox.. and down in another textbox it will show the result

Answer (score 0):

Call `rangeforloanamt` function `onkeyup` event instead of `onblur`

```
<input type="text" id="loan_amt" name="loanamt" onkeyup="rangeforloanamt(this)">
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/awqj0s8h/8/)

Comment: if i use onkeyup.. once after each number gets enter in the box it is showing alert msg

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<input type="text"  id="loan_amt" name="loanamt"  onkeyup="calemi();" onblur="rangeforloanamt(this);"/>
```

to this:

```
<input type="text"  id="loan_amt" name="loanamt"  onkeyup="rangeforloanamt(this);"/>
```

I dont know what `calemi` function is, but if you want to `alert` every type you put in. you should use `onkeyup()` function. `onblur()` function triggers when you go out the `input` textbox.

Comment: actually that is for another function.. calculating emi.. once u start putting value in the texbox.. and down in another textbox it will show the result

Comment: if i use onkeyup.. once after each number gets enter in the box it is showing alert msg

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use `keypress` if you don't want to change your keyup functionality. In keydown event you can get the entered key & check if it the first character & entered key is 2,3,or 4. I have written `checkEnteredKey()` to check this.

```js
function checkEnteredKey(field)
    {
       var enteredKey=parseInt(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.charCode));
      if((isNaN(enteredKey)&&(event.keyCode || event.charCode))||(field.value=='' && enteredKey > 1 && enteredKey<5))  {
                alert("enter loan amount between 50000 and 100000");  
                event.preventDefault();
            }
    }
function rangeforloanamt(field)
    {
        if(!(field.value >= 50000 && field.value <= 100000))
            {
                alert("enter loan amount between 50000 and 100000");  
                return false;
            }
      }
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="loan_amt" name="loanamt"  onkeyup="calemi();" onkeypress="checkEnteredKey(this);" onblur="rangeforloanamt(this);"/>
```

Comment: this to showing alert box after 1st number.. and even for >5 value its showing alter box

Comment: You mean when I enter 2 for the first time it should show alert and 2 should not be displayed?

Comment: yes, and if i have greater than 5 it should not display alert box

Comment: It is not showing alert when I am entering 6,7,8,9 as the first number...I have edited my answer. But on blur it is showing. Are talking about that?